# How to get staking balance using RPC commands

Tags: json-rpc, altcoin, proof-of-stake, staking

I enabled staking on my wallet. I want to know the staking rewards I got. Is there any rpc command exist to get staking reward balance?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, welcome to bitcoin.SE! You'll need to provide more information in order for someone to reply, right now we don't even know which cryptocurrency or software you're talking about.

Comment: Removed the [tag:bitcoin-core] tag since official Bitcoin Core clearly doesn't have any such feature.

Comment: I am not sure, whether this is the right place to ask or not. My question is regarding the Proof-of-stake coin. I want to check the PoS reward with RPC commands. Please help me with this problem

Answer (score 0):

A staking system does not exists in Bitcoin's Proof-of-Work consensus model, that being said you will not find any "staking" related functionality in the RPC API. There have been several proposals for a [Proof-of-Stake](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Proof_of_Stake) model where this would exist, but of course these have not yet been adopted or have reached any general agreement among the Bitcoin community.

Comment: Let say, coin is built on bitcoin with PoS activation. How can we get stake balance in this case?